# PHP Curl - Extraction returning blank (possibly related to cookies)

Tags: php, curl

For a little fun and not for commercial reasons, I extract data from the Racing Post website in order to create my own speed ratings for horses. I have done this for several years with no problems. I am not much of a programmer and recently, something has changed and I cannot seem to find a solution. The only thing I can suspect is that it is something to do with cookies, because now, the website will not operate unless your browser has cookies enabled.

I realise that Racing Post has probably put this in place in order to stop any form of scraping. However, as already mentioned, I am not doing this commercially and defensively, I actually load less pages doing this through Curl/Php, as oppose to having to create my own speed ratings manually (which I am currently doing! sigh).

This code worked perfectly only two months ago:

```
//CURL START
$ch = curl_init('https://www.racingpost.com/');

if($ch !== false){
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
        ));

    $card_data = mysql_real_escape_string(curl_exec($ch));

    //if($card_data === false){
    //  echo 'Error.'.curl_error($ch)."\n";
    //}
    //print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Now when the code above is ran...the return of $card_data (which is simply the home page) is blank.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated in how to regain access.

Comment: Try setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false`

Comment: You can have a look at [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html)

Comment: I have tried things like that Yolo. Nothing works.

Comment: Hmm i tested and it works with setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,`. Did you try without `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: That is very strange if it works for you. Other websites are fine with those settings, but not the one that I want. I can view the website on my browser perfectly, but when I use Curl, the return is only a blank page.